# Trigger web-hook when background search job completes on Splunk enterorice

Tags: java, splunk

I trying to automate Splunk search and export to CSV using Java SDK. Is it possible to webhook a URL from Splunk when the background job that I have started will be completed? So that I can export the CSV without waiting for the completion of search job.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a scheduled search, there is a 'Trigger Actions' section, under which you can select `Webhook`.

If you are just running an ad-hoc search that you have background'ed, you may need run a different scheduled search that monitors the `index=_audit` logs for `action=search info=completed` for your background'ed job, and use that to trigger a webhook when your background'ed job completes.